JSDefender support tsconfg with module: NodeNext and target :ES2022
I have a TS project with the following tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": false,
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "test/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "dist",
    "node_modules",
    ".vscode"
  ]
}

I am running the command jsdefender --license <licensekey> for obfustation the code but facing below error :
Use of this software constitutes acceptance of the accompanying license agreement.
Info: JSDefender version 2.7.0
Use of this software constitutes acceptance of the accompanying license agreement.
Use of this software constitutes acceptance of the accompanying license agreement.
Info: JSDefender version 2.7.0
Info: Licensed to: 
Floating Build License: 
This software may be used on binaries for general release.Concurrent Build Limit: 8
Info: JSDefender is up to date.
Info: Source tree building in progress...
**Error: Parse error found in 9 source code scripts**.
Execution time: 2s 848ms

I tried changing target in tsConfig ES2022 to ES5 or ES2015 obfuscation error gone but facing a runtime error
import {Server} from './app.js';var _0x00032D=new Server();_0x00032D.start().catch(console.error);
        ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module './app.js' does not provide an export named 'Server'
    at ModuleJob._instantiate (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:122:21)
    at async ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:188:5)


